# Adding new helper method using brew throws error

Tags: machine-learning, caffe2

I try to add a new helper function using brew,  as shown below.

```
brew.Register(testOp)
```

When i try to run above code, i get below error:

> AttributeError: Helper testOp already exists. Please change your
>   helper name.

Please help me resolve this error.

**NOTE:** `testOp` is defined in same file.

Answer (score 0):

First, we have to define the function (Our example function only calls the Abs operator):

```
def absolute_value(model, blob_in, blob_out, **kwargs):
    model.Abs(blob_in, blob_out)
```

Then, we can register the new helper function:

```
brew.Register(absolute_value)
```

Finally, we will test it:

```
model = ModelHelper(name="test")

x = np.array([[-1, 2, 3], [1, -2, 3], [1, 2, -3]])
workspace.FeedBlob('x', x.astype(np.float32))

brew.absolute_value(model, 'x', 'out')

workspace.RunNetOnce(model.net)

blob = workspace.FetchBlob('out')
print(blob)
```

The output should be:

```
[[1. 2. 3.]
 [1. 2. 3.]
 [1. 2. 3.]]
```